# Calculate the average of a cell populated by a formula

Tags: excel, average, formula

I have cells D5, G5, J5 and M5 are being calculated by `=imdiv(A5, B5) = D5`, for each of their respective cells. I want to create a formula to calculate the average of D5, G5, J5 and M5. I've tried using `=average(D5, G5, J5, M5)` and `=subtotal(101, D5, G5, J5, M5)` but both are returning a divide by zero error. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't average with the forumula it seems, and you know how many cells you have. Just set a cell, let's say `F5` as where the average is.

Then in the cell you can simply do `=(D5+G5+J5+M5)/4`, and this will give you the average of the four values.

Or, if you don't know the amount of cells, you can do `D5 = value((imdiv(A5, B5)))` (gets value of the number from string) And then doing this for each of the cells, you can then take the average using `=average(..)`

Answer (score 2):

That is because *IMDIV()* is giving you a *String*.  See:

[Aspelin's Answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-excel/average-of-complex-numbers/c1baf523-fbc5-4668-8885-d6785c98e9ac?db=5)